# Clojure Nullpointer exception

Tags: swing, clojure

I am trying to write a clojure code which generates an Image with each pixel of image having a value of XOR of its x and y co-ordinates but I am getting a NullpointerException. I am not able to figure out what is going wrong in my code

Here is my code:

```
(ns com.test
  (:import (javax.swing JFrame))
  (:gen-class))


; Each pixel has color value of xor of its x and y co-ordinates
(defn generateXorList [limit]
  (for [x (range limit)
        y (range limit)]
    [x y (bit-xor x y)]
))


(defn makeImage [seq]
  (let [frameSize 250
        frame (JFrame.)
        gfx (.getGraphics frame)]    
    (.setVisible frame true)
    (.setSize frame frameSize frameSize)
    (.setDefaultCloseOperation frame JFrame/EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
    (doseq [[x y color] seq]      
      (.setColor gfx (java.awt.Color. color))
      (.fillRect gfx x y 1 1)
      )))

;; Generate the image
(makeImage (generateXorList 250))
```

Here is the stacktrace

```
clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.NullPointerException, compiling:(/tmp/t.clj:26:1)
 at clojure.lang.Compiler.load (Compiler.java:7239)
    user$eval1125.invoke (form-init5557027396137860263.clj:1)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:6782)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:6745)
    clojure.core$eval.invoke (core.clj:3081)
    clojure.main$repl$read_eval_print__7099$fn__7102.invoke (main.clj:240)
    clojure.main$repl$read_eval_print__7099.invoke (main.clj:240)
    clojure.main$repl$fn__7108.invoke (main.clj:258)
    clojure.main$repl.doInvoke (main.clj:258)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:1523)
    clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate$fn__623.invoke (interruptible_eval.clj:58)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:152)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo (AFn.java:144)
    clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:630)
    clojure.core$with_bindings_STAR_.doInvoke (core.clj:1868)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:425)
    clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate.invoke (interruptible_eval.clj:56)
    clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$interruptible_eval$fn__665$fn__668.invoke (interruptible_eval.clj:191)
    clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$run_next$fn__660.invoke (interruptible_eval.clj:159)
    clojure.lang.AFn.run (AFn.java:22)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at com.test$makeImage.invoke (t.clj:22)
    com.test$eval1171.invoke (t.clj:27)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:6782)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.load (Compiler.java:7227)
    user$eval1125.invoke (form-init5557027396137860263.clj:1)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:6782)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:6745)
    clojure.core$eval.invoke (core.clj:3081)
    clojure.main$repl$read_eval_print__7099$fn__7102.invoke (main.clj:240)
    clojure.main$repl$read_eval_print__7099.invoke (main.clj:240)
    clojure.main$repl$fn__7108.invoke (main.clj:258)
    clojure.main$repl.doInvoke (main.clj:258)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:1523)
    clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate$fn__623.invoke (interruptible_eval.clj:58)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:152)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo (AFn.java:144)
    clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:630)
    clojure.core$with_bindings_STAR_.doInvoke (core.clj:1868)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:425)
    clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate.invoke (interruptible_eval.clj:56)
    clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$interruptible_eval$fn__665$fn__668.invoke (interruptible_eval.clj:191)
    clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$run_next$fn__660.invoke (interruptible_eval.clj:159)
    clojure.lang.AFn.run (AFn.java:22)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Please, attach the stacktrace of `NullPointerException` thrown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`JFrame.getGraphics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#getGraphics()) will return `null` until the frame is visible:

> Creates a graphics context for this component. This method will return `null` if this component is currently not displayable.

You have to first call `(.setVisible frame true)` before calling `(.getGraphics frame)` and assigning it to a local variable.

```
(defn makeImage [seq]
  (let [frameSize 250
        frame (JFrame.)]
    (.setVisible frame true)
    (.setSize frame frameSize frameSize)
    (.setDefaultCloseOperation frame JFrame/EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
    (let [gfx (.getGraphics frame)]
      (doseq [[x y color] seq]      
        (.setColor gfx (java.awt.Color. color))
        (.fillRect gfx x y 1 1)))))
```

or setup your frame using [`doto`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doto):

```
(defn makeImage [seq]
  (let [frameSize 250
        frame (doto (JFrame.)
                (.setVisible true)
                (.setSize frameSize frameSize)
                (.setDefaultCloseOperation JFrame/EXIT_ON_CLOSE))
        gfx (.getGraphics frame)]    
    (doseq [[x y color] seq]      
      (.setColor gfx (java.awt.Color. color))
      (.fillRect gfx x y 1 1))))
```

Comment: how do I assign it to a local variable?

Comment: Please, look at the enhanced answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One question.. which approach should I prefer? 1st or 2nd?

Comment: In this particular case I prefer `doto` as it encapsulates the whole setup of an object before I can use it. I would even consider extracting this part into a separate function so that `makeImage` responsibility is only "making an image" and not setting up a frame.

Comment: As you work with Swing in Clojure you might be interested in `seesaw` project which provides friendly Clojure API for Swing.

Comment: I will have a look at it! Thanks

Comment: Also one small edit ..when you are using doto macro you don't have to pass `frame` parameter to all functions..in fact it will give runtime error.